# Choosing XPath version for .net IIS apps

Tags: .net, iis, xpath, installation, xpath-2.0

We've got a .net CMS running on IIS 6 which uses XSLT templates. It seems to be running XPath 1.0 (as we can't use any 2.0 functionality).

How do we go about installing or specifying that IIS should use XPath 2.0? Is it installed per server, or can we specify which version to use on a per-application pool or per-site basis?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell (I haven't seen any definitive source on this), .NET doesn't have any support for XPath 2.0.  I've read things that suggest its so, but I can't get any 2.0 XPath functions to run without providing custom function definitions.

[You can use an external library to get 2.0 compatability, however.](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)